# How do I select OK on the following screen?

Tags: 20.04

[image]

Clicking and doubling clicking with the mouse doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and OK will illuminate, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.